# Can't extract second web-page. Cross-Origin Read Blocking

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am parsing https://www.ozon.ru/category/elektroinstrumenty-9857/

I successfully parsed the 1 page. But cant parse the second. I checked that xpath is correct.

It seems that problem deals with **Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross** because related message (error) appeared in developer's mode

> vendor.07939ff1beb01f288449.js:41 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://xapi.ozon.ru/tracker.bx/v2/composer_events with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

**How can I overcome this problem?**

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import time

URL = "https://www.ozon.ru/category/elektroinstrumenty-9857/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)


def parse_page(driver):
    res = []
    products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/a")
    print(len(products))
    for product in products:
        # print(product.get_attribute('href'))
        res.append(product.get_attribute('href'))
    return res

def get_links(driver, category="akkumulyatornye-otvertki-9902"):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if i == 1:
            url = "https://www.ozon.ru/category/{}/".format(category)
        else:
            url = "https://www.ozon.ru/category/{}/?page={}".format(category, i)
        driver.get(url)
        cur_links = parse_page(driver)
        res.append(cur_links)
        if len(cur_links) < 30:
            break
        time.sleep(6)
    return res

ll = get_links(driver, category="akkumulyatornye-otvertki-9902")
```

**UPDATE**

found that i can use

> chrome %U --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating

Is there convinient way to add this feature automatically with python?

Answer (score -1):

It simply means the developers of that page don't want people reading the contents automatically (with bots) and have added security measurements to achieve this.

Comment: thank yoy, but my question - How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: First of all, you should check if the content is copyrighted. If it is, you should not find another way.
If the site has blocked this, the developers are doing everything to make sure you can't scrape the page. You just can't. The website owner(s) protect their page from is so others can't profit. I'm sorry, but that's the truth.